# Spaces between #define arguments

Tags: c++, c, macros

I was confused with the concept that we shouldn't have spaces in `#define` arguments.

I think the only restriction is that we shouldn't have spaces between the macro name and the immediate `(` bracket. Am I correct? Am I not supposed to put spaces even inside the `()` brackets?

Is the below notation correct

```
#define AVERAGE_NUMS( min_val, max_val ) ((min_val + max_val) / 2)
```

Guys, my above #define C++ statement is just an example. I am actually concerned about spaces while using #define. Anyway Thanks for your answers.

Comment: don't use macros in C++!

Comment: Have you tried to see if it works?

Comment: max_val is not same as Max_val, this might be issue.

Comment: sorry typo it is max_val

Comment: A useful tutorial about C macro is http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/cpreprocessor.html

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz : why r we not suppose to use macro's in cpp. are u sure.. its very quite common to use macro either in c or cpp

Comment: To both user2104352 and Barket Macros can be used. Just for header multiple protection. The reason not to use macros for other uses in C++ is that you have the protection by the compiler of making sure it is type safe.

Comment: @Ed Most compilers support `#pragma once` for now. Anyway, we are not supposed to use macros mostly because we have superior alternatives, like inline template functions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it's correct. But you should enclose each of the arguments in brackets

```
#define AVERAGE_NUMS( min_val, max_val ) (((min_val) + (max_val)) / 2)
```

to avoid operator precedence issues.

Comment: No this doesn't "avoid side effects", it avoids effects of surprising interaction of precedences.

Comment: @vonbrand Changed to a better term.

Answer (score 4):

**In C**, when using macros for small computations like that, you should always put each parameter in the expression in brackets, like:

```
#define AVERAGE_NUMS(min_val, max_val) (((min_val) + (max_val)) / 2)
```

The spaces within the macro's argument list are optional, so they don't "hurt". As you already said, a space *before* the opening bracket changes the meaning of the macro: It will then take no parameter and replaces its occurrence with both what you wanted to be the parameter list as well as the "expression".

If you don't put the arguments in the expression in brackets, you can encounter strange results because the operator precedence might change your expression. This is because macros are just text replacement rules and thus don't respect anything of the programming language (C).

A small example where it fails (This is a strange example, I admit, but there are other functions you'd write as macros where "normal" usages fail):

```
AVERAGE_NUMS(1 << x, y)
```

Using your macro definition, this will expand to

```
((1 << x + y) / 2)           // Operator precedence:  1 << (x + y)
```

But using the macro definition from above, it will expand to

```
(((1 << x) + (y)) / 2)       // Operator precedence:  (1 << x) + y
```

---

**In C++**, I strongly advise you not to use macros unless you *really* have to.

A way better method for calculating the average of two numbers without requiring to specify the type is to use a template method:

```
template<typename T>
T average_nums(T min_val, T max_val) {
    return (min_val + max_val) / T(2);
}
```

If you are concerned about the performance, you should note that all modern compilers handle this piece of code the same way as it was a macro definition, namely they **inline** the code. This means that there is no function *call* involved, but the expression `avg(a, b)` gets replaced by `(a + b) / 2`.

The difference between this and macros is that a macro is only a text replacement which happens during *precompilation*, so the actual compilation step will see something like `(a + b) / 2` instead of `avg(a, b)`.

Comment: @RoeeGavirel Thank you, I didn't see that.

Comment: @leemes : There might be problems using macro's. But my question was not that. Anyway thanks for your answer

Answer (score 3):

You are correct, no spaces between macro name and the immediately following open bracket. Spaces anywhere else == fine.

Be careful about the names used for your macro arguments, if you've got a variable called the same name as an argument you'll have strange things happening... For example in your example your argument is `max_val`, but you've typed `Max_val` in the macro, so if there was a variable `Max_val` where you happened to use this macro the code would compile fine, but not compile in other places...

Personally I always have a prefix _ on macro names to help avoid such situations... But purists have told me that underscore is reserved and should not be used, but stuff them :)

Answer (score 3):

I believe the following excerpts from the C standard from 1999 cover the question of how spaces are treated within macros and they do indeed state that spaces are nothing more than a token separator, with the exception of the case where we differentiate between object-like macros and function-like macros based on whether there's a space between the macro name and the immediately following it opening parenthesis.

**5.1.1.2 Translation phases**

...

1.3 `The source file is decomposed into preprocessing tokens and sequences of white-space characters (including comments). ... Each comment is replaced by one space character. New-line characters are retained. Whether each nonempty sequence of white-space characters other than new-line is retained or replaced by one space character is implementation-defined.`

1.4 `Preprocessing directives are executed, macro invocations are expanded, and
_Pragma unary operator expressions are executed. ... All preprocessing directives are then deleted.`

1.7 `White-space characters separating tokens are no longer significant.` Each preprocessing token is converted into a token. The resulting tokens are syntactically and semantically analyzed and translated as a translation unit.

...

**6.4 Lexical elements**

**Syntax**

**token:**

- keyword
- identifier
- constant
- string-literal
- punctuator

**`preprocessing-token:`**

- header-name
- identifier
- pp-number
- character-constant
- string-literal
- punctuator
- each non-white-space character that cannot be one of the above

**Semantics**

... `Preprocessing tokens can be separated by white space; this consists of comments (described later), or white-space characters (space, horizontal tab, new-line, vertical tab, and form-feed), or both. As described in 6.10, in certain circumstances during translation phase 4, white space (or the absence thereof) serves as more than preprocessing token separation.` ...

**6.10 Preprocessing directives**

**Syntax**

...

- # define identifier replacement-list new-line
- `# define identifier lparen identifier-listopt ) replacement-list new-line`
- `# define identifier lparen ... ) replacement-list new-line`
- `# define identifier lparen identifier-list , ... ) replacement-list new-line`

`lparen:`

`a ( character not immediately preceded by white-space`

**6.10.3 Macro replacement**

**Constraints**

3 `There shall be white-space between the identifier and the replacement list in the definition of an object-like macro.`

**Semantics**

10 A preprocessing directive of the form

- `# define identifier lparen identifier-listopt ) replacement-list new-line`
- `# define identifier lparen ... ) replacement-list new-line`
- `# define identifier lparen identifier-list , ... ) replacement-list new-line`

defines a `function-like` macro with arguments, similar syntactically to a function call.

Answer (score -1):

The question is already nine years old, but I think most answers miss the rationale behind the "no spaces before the opening paren" rule (or try to explain why macros are dangerous and templates are better...). The point is that you can use `#define` to define macros without parameters (i.e. constants) as well as real macros with parameters. Now, if the expansion of a constant starts with an opening parenthesis, the preprocessor must differentiate between the parenthesis belonging to the expansion and the parenthesis starting the macro parameter list. And this is done by (you guessed it) whitespace before the parenthesis.

Example: if you have `#define FOUR (2+2)` the `(` is interpreted as belonging to the expansion and wherever you write `FOUR` its expanded to `(2+2)`. Note, that the parens are necessary, because otherwise without parens expressions like `FOUR*3` would be expanded to `2+2*3` which is 8 - not what you expected. On the other hand, if you define `#define DOUBLE(a) ((a)+(a))` the parenthesis starts the parameter list and `DOUBLE(2)` expands to `((2)+(2))`, whereas if you had wrongly written `#define DOUBLE (a) ((a)+(a))` then `DOUBLE(2)` would be expanded to `(a) ((a)+(a))(2)`, resulting in a compile error.

Comment: It seems OP knew the rationale behind "no space before `(`", and was about spaces in the parameter list, rather than there.

Comment: @chqrlie I knew that this comment would come, but a) the question was not about making macros a bit less unsafe than they are anyway, and b) how does parenthesizing help with e.g. `DOUBLE(++i)`? Not at all. If you define a function you can write either `void foo()` or `void foo ()`, there is no difference, but if you define a macro there is one, and it's the rationale for that, that I wanted to point out.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Sorry, but I don't think so. If he had known the rationale behind it, he wouldn't have asked, because when parsing macro parameters there never is any ambiguity or change in meaning, whether you have spaces around them or not. But if you have space(s) before the opening parenthesis it gives the definition a completely different meaning.

Comment: @chqrlie Happy now?

Comment: @ElmarZander: yes Danke :)